# Chrome extension's content script not getting injected into any web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a simple chrome extension in which I'm trying to include a content script in these specific webpages. But the problem is they aren't getting included in the website. I checked using the Chrome's Developer tools tool. 
Then I set the match_urls to all pages, but still they don't get included.

Here's the **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TestExten",
  "description": "Test description.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document.end",
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/", "https://*/",
    "cookies"
  ],
}
```

and the **content.js**:

```
alert("loaded");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     alert("received message");
});
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the extension is getting installed and enabled?

Comment: It is `document_end` (instead of `document.end`)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

The parameter `run_at` accepts `document_end`, not `document.end`. So your manifest should look like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TestExten",
  "description": "Test description.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/", "https://*/",
    "cookies"
  ],
}
```